# Extract rows with duplicates entries in one column satisfying a given condition in another column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, duplicates

I have a sample dataframe with duplicate entries in the first column given below:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(rep(101,3),rep(102,2),103,rep(104,3)),Type=c(2,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,2),sex=c(0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0))
df
  ID Type sex
1 101    2   0
2 101    1   0
3 101    1   0
4 102    1   1
5 102    2   1
6 103    1   1
7 104    3   0
8 104    1   0
9 104    2   0
```

**Question:** For each variable 'ID', I want the rows to start from where the first occurrence of the variable 'Type' is 1 (i.e. Type=1).

I know for each ID, the position satisfying the condition **Type=1** using the code below:

```
aggregate(df$Type,list(ID=df$ID),function(x) match(1,x))
 ID x
1 101 2
2 102 1
3 103 1
4 104 2
```

but I have not been able to solve the problem.

**Desired Output:** The output should look like this:

```
df.result <- data.frame(ID=c(101,101,102,102,103,104,104),Type=c(1,1,1,2,1,1,2),sex=c(0,0,1,1,1,0,0))
df.result
 ID Type sex
1 101    1   0
2 101    1   0
3 102    1   1
4 102    2   1
5 103    1   1
6 104    1   0
7 104    2   0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `match` with `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% slice(match(1, Type) : n())

#    ID  Type   sex
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1   101     1     0
#2   101     1     0
#3   102     1     1
#4   102     2     1
#5   103     1     1
#6   104     1     0
#7   104     2     0
```

Or using `filter`

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(row_number() >= match(1, Type))
```

---

In base R, we can use `ave` like :

```
subset(df, as.logical(ave(Type, ID, FUN = function(x) seq_along(x) >= match(1, x))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `slice`, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 slice(which(Type == 1)[1]:n())
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 7 x 3
> # Groups:   ID [4]
>      ID  Type   sex
>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
> 1   101     1     0
> 2   101     1     0
> 3   102     1     1
> 4   102     2     1
> 5   103     1     1
> 6   104     1     0
> 7   104     2     0
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using `cumsum()`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(cumsum(Type==1) > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution using

```
dfout <- do.call(rbind,
                 c(make.row.names = F,
                   Map(function(v) v[head(which(v$Type==1),1):nrow(v),],split(df,df$ID))))
```

such that

```
> dfout
   ID Type sex
1 101    1   0
2 101    1   0
3 102    1   1
4 102    2   1
5 103    1   1
6 104    1   0
7 104    2   0
```